# Building Active Directory Operations in IIB without Java or JCN

Tags: active-directory, messagebroker, entity-sql

The Case is : to build an `integration` `service` with `active directory`, this `service` has many `operations`
such as `create user`, `activate user`, `change password` , ...etc I have developed theses operations using `JCN`
but,
the client refused any `java` implementations inside the `service` even calling `java` `apis` inside `esql modules`,

My question is :
from my experience it is impossible to build this service without any Java implementations if it is impossible using ESQL please tell me? If it was pure `esql` or `tcpip`?

Comment: There is a web service interface for AD, called ADWS: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391908%28v=ws.10%29.aspx I've not used it before but seems like an option for you.

Comment: @AttilaRepasi this is the first time i here about it it so interesting to try it , but from my experience to make operations on `active directory` i must develop them using `java`. thanx again